# Crack in my wine glass

Tags: modeling

I am doing this tutorial to make a wine glass with the spin tool. After applying the spin tool, a subdivision surface modifier and the solidify modifier my glass looks like in the image. Somehow I did something wrong resulting in a "crack" in my wine glass. When I did this process again I am sure that I set the spin tool at 36 steps and 360 degrees. What did i forget ? Hope I did not ask a question that what was already answered

[image]

[here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xwr1nvkz2wq5b7u/appetizer-series.blend?dl=0) is the blender file

Comment: Try to remove doubles

Comment: I did remove doubles

Comment: Are there inside faces on the seam?

Comment: It looks like you have a face inside the glass wall.

Comment: i updated my question and added a link to the blender file

Comment: don't use the spin tool for this kind of stuff, use the Screw modifier to 'Lathe' a profile around. The benefit of Screw is that you can update your profile shape interactive, while the Spin tool is just a one-off operation that you have to undo if it isn't good.

Comment: I will try the screw modifier but now I have done this work with the spin tool  I want to understand what I did wrong ;)

Comment: I added an answer explaining what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: After looking at the .blend file removing doubles fixed it since you were using a solidify modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a face inside the glass wall, the subsurf modifier does not handle this kind of non-manifold geometry very well.

Look closely, see the face within the wall.
[image]

To get rid of it just go into wireframe view and select the spare face and delete it with <kbd>Del</kbd> > *faces*.
[image]

**Edit:**

I looked at your .blend file and since in your particular case you are using a solidify modifier to get the glass thickness you can't directly select the offending faces and delete them.  Just go into edit mode and select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then hit <kbd>W</kbd> > *remove doubles*.  This will merge the duplicate vertices along the crack.

Here is a comparison:
[image]

See how before I removed doubles, when I selected the edge loop at the location of the crack only have “tails” in one direction?  This means there are double verts at that location.
[image]

Comment: @JanScherders  I just looked at your .blend file and it seems that you are using a solidify modifier.  I just hit [W] > *remove doubles* and it worked fine.

Comment: you are right !! but before I used the "remove doubles" command in the tool bar and that did not remove the doubles ... Is this another command ??? Anyway, thanks

Comment: @JanScherders You have to select all first, that's all I can think of.  They are the same thing.